Movie about a paranoid war veteran who thought he have found terrorists in Los Angeles
The plot takes place in Los Angeles and its surrounding area. I remember that the film starts with the arrival by plane of a young woman in Los Angeles. She goes to some kind of mission where a priest helps homeless. She stays there because she knows the priest. She is looking for her father who is a war (maybe Vietnam) veteran. 
Then, the film shows her father, who lives in a van. He is paranoid and he is looking for terrorists. He spends his days watching suspect people (basically every non white man) and communicates by radio with another (or several) war veterans. At some point, he sees an Arab moving around barrels and thinks the barrels contain some chemicals to make a bomb.
The veteran follows the people he suspects and arrives somewhere outside Los Angeles, in an isolated place where there are a few houses. He discovers that the barrels had nothing to do with a terrorist plot, but I don't remember what they contained.
Also, at some point, the woman finds her father and talk to him.
The film is not recent, maybe from the 1980s, I don't think there were any mobile phones in it. It shows mostly poor neighborhoods of Los Angeles.

I believe the movie is called Land of Plenty from 2004.
You can watch trailers on youtube to determine if that is the movie or not.

Can you provide the youtube link so the person who asked the question knows where to look?

Thanks, that's the film. I remembered wrongly that the war veteran was the woman's father, actually he was her uncle.

No one trailer I watched on youtube was completely useful in identifying the movie, that is why I did not recommend any of them.  It is best to go to youtube.com and type: movie land of plenty.  Then just start watching as many different trailers as necessary.  Or, just do an Internet search for: movie land of plenty.  I make the assumption that most users on here are more Internet literate than I and that the information I originally provided would be enough (and it was).
